# Stuck on Pong Game in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I am stuck on this pong game and cannot figure out what is wrong. I have been working on it for about 2 weeks and as soon as I started making the paddle hittable it threw me a million errors and I couldn't fix it from there. I've been trying to just get rid of the errors for about a week.

Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "animationTest.py", line 75, in <module>
ball_canv = Ball(canvas, paddle_canv)
File "animationTest.py", line 26, in __init__
self.move_active()
File "animationTest.py", line 50, in move_active
self.ball_update()
File "animationTest.py", line 37, in ball_update
if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
File "animationTest.py", line 42, in hit_paddle
paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.Paddle.pad)
AttributeError: Ball instance has no attribute 'Paddle'
```

Code:

```
   from Tkinter import *
   import time
   import random

   HEIGHT = 500
   WIDTH = 800
   COLOR = 'blue'
   SIZE = 50

   root = Tk()

   canvas = Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg=COLOR)
   canvas.pack()


   class Ball:

      def __init__(self, canvas, paddle):
         self.ball = canvas.create_oval(0, 0, SIZE, SIZE, fill='black')
         self.label = Label(root, text = 'score: {}')
         self.speedx = 6
         self.speedy = 6
         self.hit_top = False
         self.active = True
         self.canvas = canvas
         self.move_active()

      def ball_update(self):
         canvas.move(self.ball, self.speedx, self.speedy)
         pos = canvas.coords(self.ball)
         if pos[1] <= 500:
            self.speedy = -6
         if pos[3] <= 100:
            self.hit_top = True
         if pos[2] >= 800:
            self.speedx = -6
         if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.speedy = -6
            self.speedx = random.randrange(-6,6)

      def hit_paddle(self, pos):
         paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.Paddle.pad)
         if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
               return True
         return False

      def move_active(self):
         if self.active:
            self.ball_update()
            root.after(1, self.move_active)



   class Paddle:


      def __init__(self, canvas):
         self.pad = canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,100,10, fill='red')
         canvas.bind('<Motion>', self.motion)
         self.active = True
         self.move_active

      def motion(self, event):
         '''update paddle coordinates using current mouse position'''
         canvas.coords(self.pad, event.x-50, 0, event.x+50, 10)

      def move_active(self):
         if self.active:
            self.motion()
            root.after(1, self.move_active)


   paddle_canv = Paddle(canvas)
   ball_canv = Ball(canvas, paddle_canv)

   while ball_canv.self.hit_top == False:
      padddle_canv.motion()
      root.update_idletasks()
      root.update()
      time.sleep(0.01)  



   root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `Ball` class `__init__` method, you forgot to assign `paddle` to `self`, I think. Try modifying it to:

```
class Ball:

  def __init__(self, canvas, paddle):
     self.ball = canvas.create_oval(0, 0, SIZE, SIZE, fill='black')
     self.label = Label(root, text = 'score: {}')
     self.speedx = 6
     self.speedy = 6
     self.hit_top = False
     self.active = True
     self.canvas = canvas
     self.paddle = paddle
     self.move_active()
```

(Thanks @PRMoureu for catching an issue with placement)

And then also a small tweak to `hit_paddle` to call the newly assigned `self.paddle` attribute (note I lowercased `self.Paddle` to `self.paddle` to match the new line in `__init__`):

```
def hit_paddle(self, pos):
     paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.pad)
     if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
        if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
           return True
     return False
```

Comment: (need to move up this assignation, before `self.move_active()`)

Comment: @PRMoureu Thanks I didn't realize this was such a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting "AttributeError: Ball instance has no attribute 'Paddle'" says it all. `Ball` class doesn't have a `Paddle` instance variable.

To fix this, add the following line to your constructor:

`self.Paddle = paddle`

The above line will store reference to paddle as an instance variable in `Ball` class.